# Spring Session : "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit

Tags: spring

I am using Spring session to store the session information in db which i have already configured using Hibernate.

Now I am using the existing Spring  MVC application to store the session information in DB,

But I am ruuning into error, so could someone help me to resolve this issue

```
public class WebApplication implements WebApplicationInitializer{

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    // register the configuration class here
    dispatcherServlet.register(WebAppConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherServlet));

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("InternalSite",
            new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));


    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/api/*");

}}
```

WebAppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    System.out.println("in WebAppConfig class");
    configurer.enable();
}

/**
 * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
 */
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}}
```

DatalessJdbcSessionConfig

```
@EnableJdbcDatalessHttpSession
public class DatalessJdbcSessionConfig extends SessionCookieConfig{

@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    System.out.println("data source configured   :  "+datasource.getClass());
    System.out.println("in DatalessJdbcSessionConfig class datasource");
    return datasource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    System.out.println("in DatalessJdbcSessionConfig class transactionManager");
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}}
```

Initilizer:

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

public Initializer() {
    super(DatalessJdbcSessionConfig.class);
}}
```

Error:

```
2016-12-13 14:30:19,742 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status reportWFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ArgumentTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.HtmlEscapeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.NestedPathTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.TransformTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ButtonTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxesTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.PasswordInputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.TextareaTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./example (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-ear-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".deploymentCompleteService] WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./example
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens in jboss is there are some subsystem defined in standalone.xml and out of them some subsystems depends on some other subsystems internally which we are not aware about. So in this case you can directly remove jsf extension and its corresponding subsystem from your standalone.xml if your application doesn't require jsf or you can exclude jsf subsystem by declaring its exclusion in jboss-deployment-descriptor.xml.

Please google it, how to exclude modules in jboss .